# CSS Menu collapsing at 540px but I can't see why

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a site more mobile friendly - I didn't do the original menu code, though, and it's a bit of a mess. The header in particular is proving problematic.

Ideally, it should be centered at all times, and if the screen resolution becomes too narrow to fit it all across the top, each menu option should be presented on a different line.  The site is [redacted]

The CSS for the menu is here:

```
#cssmenu > ul {
  max-width: 640px;
  min-width 200px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
 border: 0px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -o-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
 
#cssmenu > ul li {
  display: inline-block;
text-align: left;
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub {
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub:hover ul {
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ece6e8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00000;
  border-top: 0 none;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul li {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub > a {
 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 90% -95%;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub > a.active,
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub > a:hover {
  z-index: 10;
  background-position: 90% 195%;
}
#cssmenu > ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px 11px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
}
#cssmenu > ul li a.active,
#cssmenu > ul li a:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  z-index: 10;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #000;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #cssmenu > ul {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li#responsive-tab {
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li#responsive-tab a {
    background-position: 95% -35%;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li#responsive-tab a:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-position: 95% 135%;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li.right {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub {
    position: relative;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul {
    display: block;
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 0 none;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul li {
    display: block !important;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul li a span {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 24px;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub > a {
    background-image: none;
  }
}
/* Make sure they show even if hidden in mobile view by JS */
@media (min-width: 100px) {
  #cssmenu > ul > li.collapsed {
    display: inline-block !important;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
  }
 
  #cssmenu > ul ul li.collapsed {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

What's happening is it will resize down to 540px, then the menu collapses.

The menu looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li id="menu-item-633" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="http://rollsupreme.com/product-category/gikimono/"><span>Gi/Kimono</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-603" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="http://rollsupreme.com/product-category/t-shirts/"><span>T Shirts</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-604" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="http://rollsupreme.com/product-category/hoodies/"><span>Hoodies</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-605" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="http://rollsupreme.com/product-category/rashguards/"><span>Rashguards</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-606" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="http://rollsupreme.com/product-category/shorts/"><span>Shorts</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-607" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="http://rollsupreme.com/product-category/sweaters/"><span>Sweaters</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-527" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="http://rollsupreme.com/blog"><span>Blog</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-646" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://rollsupreme.com/us/"><span>ABOUT US</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-528" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://rollsupreme.com/cart/"><span>Cart</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-529" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://rollsupreme.com/checkout/"><span>Checkout</span></a>
```

If I force the width of the menu to 200px in Firebug, it will do what I want it to, but I can't get it to resize dynamically.

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't see where the collapsing behaviour is coming from.

Any tips would be very much appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to a file that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the file expires or is deleted. Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Comment: Add the html from your issue or we will not be able to help you. Put the html and the css in stackoverflow post it will create an helpful snippet for people who wants to help you.

Comment: Make a fiddle that may help users to answer your question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a style on line 238 of http://rollsupreme.com/wp-content/themes/test-nerdy/framework/style.php?ver=1.0.7 which is hiding your list menu items when the width is less than 600px which comes under a media query. So when you resize to a size less than 600px all the elements dissapear

```
#cssmenu > ul li {
    display: none;
}
```

You will want to change this to

```
#cssmenu > ul li {
    display:block;
}
```

Each menu item is now displayed on one row each which is standard for a mobile menu.